# JSON performance

Tags: java, json

I have to turn a `List<Map>` into a JSON string. The `Map`s are flat and containing primitive and String data. Right now I'm using GSON. Basically like this:

```
List<Map> list = new ArrayList();

Map map = new HashMap();
map.put("id",100);
map.put("name","Joe");
map.put("country","US");
// ...
list.add(map);

Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().disableHtmlEscaping().setPrettyPrinting().create(); 
Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.createStarted(); // guava's stopwatch 
String s = gson.toJson(list);
System.err.println("toJson laps " + sw);
return s;
```

The `list` may have 100 entries and each map aprox. 20 fields. GSON really takes long time to create the JSON string. The JSON string will be returned by a HTTP response and right now it took too much time (8000ms). So I try other ones: json-smart, jackson, etc. But no one gives a significant speed boost. I trace the JSON string creation as the hot spot in execution time.

For 100 x 20 fields I really won't expect more than a second but it takes significant much more time. Is there any heal for this ?

**Update**
I have overseen some BLOB data that is returned. Thank you all.

Comment: 8000ms are for the entire request? Have you already measured Map-to-Json time too?

Comment: Because of the simplicity of the structure, I would give manual construction (`StringBuilder`) a shot

Comment: Can you show how you are measuring the time it takes GSON to create your JSON string. I create much bigger JSON strings with GSON than that and don't have a performance issue at all.

Comment: [Some benchmarks on various JSON serialization tools](https://github.com/eishay/jvm-serializers/wiki)

Comment: Just a guess but if you are measuring the total response time I would bet that your time is being taken up by db access rather than the GSON part. Check that you are not doing something silly like making a db query for every object in your map.

Comment: @bhspencer yes, really I create the List<Map> from a db connection into memory. Then calling toJson() on the in-memory List. Db access around 600ms.

Comment: Are you certain you only have 100*20 fields?

Comment: Ok, seems my SSCCE is NOT really what I'm doing. The performance hot-spot is'nt GSON. It is the way I feed the List. Thanks to all!

Answer (score 2):

You better use Jackson2

https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson

Java EE 7 has also a new JSON processing API, brand new!

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/package-summary.html

Profiling the different libs will provide answers. For enterprise applications, I never use GSON.

Comment: At first I started trying to find some benchmark example for why GSON did belong in production enterprise applications (primarily because this is exactly the tool I use in this type of application), but the more I've looked into things the more good things I've read about [Boon](https://github.com/boonproject/boon), maybe I should update my assumptions :)

Comment: Make sure to benchmark with realistic setting, including warmup. NEVER just start up JVM, do a single call to read/write JSON, assume that number is meaningful. Half of "benchmarks" people post make this mistake, and I am guessing it might be applicable here -- first call overhead has little relevance to steady-state performance. And FWTW, latest versions of GSON have acceptable performance; but some older versions (pre-2.3 I think) had really really bad performance when readin/writing POJOs. So with GSON use latest version.

Comment: And on Oracle's: don't bother. There is nothing in there worth using, absolutely nothing better or even as good as what GSON, Jackson and Boon offer. I have no idea why Oracle wasted their time there, given plethora of solid existing solutions. Maybe just to tie developers to Oracle standards, instead of OSS solutions.

Comment: Can confirm: oracle's json lib is terribly slow. Jackson is amongst the fastest. I consider gson quite slow for a modern lib. Here is a benchmark I wrote using JMH comparing a dozen of java json libs: https://github.com/fabienrenaud/java-json-benchmark

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want to write benchmarks, use JMH. Writing high quality benchmarks isn't easy and JMH does a lot of the heavy lifting for you (although there are still a few gotchas).
2. If you wonder which Java Json library serializes/deserializes faster for various payload sizes, you can look at [this extensive benchmark](https://github.com/fabienrenaud/java-json-benchmark) which compares a dozen of them with JMH. Fasted is [dsljson](https://github.com/ngs-doo/dsl-json), second is [jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson). Gson is actually pretty slow for a 'modern' lib.